# input boxes not displaying during automated test

Tags: angular, protractor

While running a test, a couple of input boxes are supposed to be displayed (unhidden) after a dropdown box option is selected.  During normal, manual testing, this works fine.  However, when I run my protractor test, the boxes fail to display.  Even if I put a browser.pause() command to break execution, that browser instance will fail to respond to the dropdown.  **My question is, has anyone run into a similar situation?**

Angular 2.0.0
Protractor 4.0.9
Typescript 2.0.2

1. Open search page
2. select dropdown to open second dropdown choice
3. select second dropdown choice to open first and last name input boxes

** first and last name input boxes do *not* appear under protractor run tests **

The input boxes on this page are straight text input elements (as opposed to a material design input element).  Also, when I inspect the page, the hidden elements in question exist, but remain behind a div element that is hidden. As stated above, manually testing this works fine. But running it with protractor with or without pausing execution does not display the desired elements.

Comment: A random thought: could it depend on the size of the browser window? Have you tried maximizing the browser window in your test? Also, could it be a problem with this particular build of the app under test? Thanks.

Comment: After a discussion with one of our devs, it appears that extraneous code in the app sort of duplicates processes already available in Angular2.  So there is likely some bug in our code (not necessarily the automation code).

I did try sizing the browser window both manually and use setSize.